# Prove $f(x)=(\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert},\lVert x\rVert)$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

I was trying to prove $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}-\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^n\times\mathbb{R^{+}}$. The homeomorphism I figured out is $f(x)=(\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert},\lVert x\rVert)$.

It is easy to show the bijectivity yet I have no idea how to prove $f$ is continuous and  $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: typo? - you mean $S^n \times {\mathbb R}^+$?

Comment: Did you try computing the inverse? If I give you unit vector $u$ and non-negative scalar $r$, can you find the $x$ such that $(u, r) = (x/\|x\|, \|x\|)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\mathbb{R}^n-\{x\}$ homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901842/why-is-mathbbrn-x-homeomorphic-to-sn-1-times-mathbbr)

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn While highly relevant, I wouldn't say that the dupe target is appropriate. None of the answers address the specific concerns in this question; at best, one of the answers below specifies this map and claims it's a homeomorphism without proof.

Comment: @peterag yeah there was a typo. Now I have fixed it.

Comment: What concerns me most is to show $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both continuous. I have read related posts on mse, but none of them showed the proof I need.

Comment: Given your map, I thought so... on the other hand, as in the linked question, $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^+$, via $x\mapsto e^x$, so...

Comment: If you are having troubles computing the inverse think about how you can recover $x$ from $a=\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}$ and $b={\lVert x\rVert}$.

Comment: @tetra I know the inverse should be $f^{-1}(\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert},\lVert x\rVert)=\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}\cdot \lVert x\rVert=x$

Comment: which is ______

Comment: @tetra I need the formal proof, that is which troubles me.

Comment: what troubles you? you have explicit formulas for $f$ and it's inverse

Comment: @tetra Ok, after thinking for a while I guess I have grasped the key of proving $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Essentially $f^{-1}$ is $g(r,s)=rs$ with $r\in\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ and $s\in\mathbb{R}$. So basically $g$ is a contraction map and contraction map can be proved continuous resorting to $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: You can think of $g:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous. Then you restrict $g$ to $S^n\times\mathbb{R}^+$, lets call this $\tilde g$, which again is a continuous function. Since then $0$ is not in the image of $\tilde g$ you can delete it from the codomain of $\tilde g$ (which doesn't change anything about the continuity) to finally yield $f^{-1}$.

Comment: I of course mean $g:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Sorry for the typo.